# "MultiSelection" not working properly when using "Server Side Filtering" MudBlazor MudTable in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I started using MudBlazor in a Blazor WebAssembly project.
The problem is that when I use server side filtering and pagination in MudTable, MultiSelection not working properly. I can select all the rows by clicking "Select All" checkbox but **selectAll checkbox remains unchecked when All are selected**; and **unable to unselect all again**.
Unselect only working 1 by 1.

I am using this link:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEQcYHEKpSAoCWSn

I appreciate your helps.

Comment: I have noticed the same issue, not sure if this is a bug. As a workaround I use a "Refresh" button that main function is to reload server data, but also clear selectedItems collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the code like this it works.

```
<MudTable ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<Element>>>(ServerReload))"
        @ref="table"
        CustomHeader="true"
        @bind-SelectedItems="selectedItems1" 
         MultiSelection="true"
        RowClassFunc="@SelectedRowClassFunc" 
        OnRowClick="RowClickEvent" 
        RowsPerPageChanged="OnRowsPerPageChanged"
        T="Element">
        
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Periodic Elements</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudTextField T="string" ValueChanged="@(s=>OnSearch(s))" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
     <HeaderContent>
        <MudTHeadRow IgnoreCheckbox="true">
            <MudTh>
                <MudCheckBox T="bool" Checked="IsSelectAllChecked" CheckedChanged="@Select"></MudCheckBox>
            </MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Number)">Nr</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Name)">Name</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Position)">Position</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Molar)">Mass</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        </MudTHeadRow>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <NoRecordsContent>
        <MudText>No matching records found</MudText>
    </NoRecordsContent>
    <LoadingContent>
        <MudText>Loading...</MudText>
    </LoadingContent>
   <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{1, 5, 10}" />
    </PagerContent>
    <FooterContent>
        <MudTd colspan="5">Select All</MudTd>
    </FooterContent>
</MudTable>
    <MudText >@($"{selectedItems1.Count} items selected")</MudText>
    <MudText Inline="true">Selected items: @(selectedItems1==null ? "" : string.Join(", ", selectedItems1.OrderBy(x=>x.Sign).Select(x=>x.Sign)))</MudText>


@code {
    private IEnumerable<Element> pagedData;
    private MudTable<Element> table;

    private int totalItems;
    private string searchString = null;

    private List<string> clickedEvents = new();
    private HashSet<Element> selectedItems1 = new HashSet<Element>();

    private async Task<TableData<Element>> ServerReload(TableState state)
    {
        IEnumerable<Element> data = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
        await Task.Delay(300);
        data = data.Where(element =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
                return true;
            if (element.Sign.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            if (element.Name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            if ($"{element.Number} {element.Position} {element.Molar}".Contains(searchString))
                return true;
            return false;
        }).ToArray();
        totalItems = data.Count();
        switch (state.SortLabel)
        {
            case "nr_field":
                data = data.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, o => o.Number);
                break;
            case "sign_field":
                data = data.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, o => o.Sign);
                break;
            case "name_field":
                data = data.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, o => o.Name);
                break;
            case "position_field":
                data = data.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, o => o.Position);
                break;
            case "mass_field":
                data = data.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, o => o.Molar);
                break;
        }

        pagedData = data.Skip(state.Page * state.PageSize).Take(state.PageSize).ToArray();
        return new TableData<Element>() {TotalItems = totalItems, Items = pagedData};
    }

    private void OnRowsPerPageChanged(int pageSize)
    {
        selectedItems1.Clear();
    }

    private void OnSelectedItemsChanged(HashSet<Element> elements)
    {
        clickedEvents.Add("Selected items changed");
    }



    private void OnSearch(string text)
    {
        searchString = text;
        table.ReloadServerData();
    }

     private void RowClickEvent(TableRowClickEventArgs<Element> tableRowClickEventArgs)
    {
        clickedEvents.Add("Row has been clicked");
    }

    private string SelectedRowClassFunc(Element element, int rowNumber)
    {
        return selectedItems1.Contains(element) ? "selected" : string.Empty;
    }

    private bool IsSelectAllChecked
    {
        get
        {
            var currentPage = table.CurrentPage;
            var rowsPerPage =table.RowsPerPage;
       
            var currentPageItems = table.FilteredItems.Skip(currentPage * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);

            if (!selectedItems1.Any(x => currentPageItems.Any(y => x == y)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    private void Select()
    {
        var currentPage = table.CurrentPage;
        var rowsPerPage = table.RowsPerPage;
       
        var currentPageItems = table.FilteredItems.Skip(currentPage * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);

        if (!selectedItems1.Any(x => currentPageItems.Any(y => x == y)))
        {
            foreach(var item in currentPageItems)
            {
                selectedItems1.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var item in currentPageItems)
            {
                selectedItems1.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @ref="table" and table.ReloadServerData() helped me a ton, thank you.